# Why is it not necessary for an inherited class of Applet to override all its methods as Applet class is an abstract class

Tags: java, applet

To create an applet program, programmer needs to inherit the Applet class from applet package also Applet class being an abstract class which means its inherited class must override all the methods in an Applet class but that is not the case with Applet. The programmer may or may out override all the methods of an abstract class. Why?If an inherited class does not override all the methods of abstract class then by default that inherited class also becomes an abstract class. Then why is it not the case with Applet and its sub classs.

Answer (score 2):

The `java.applet.Applet` class in fact is *not* abstract, and is defined with the following signature:

```
public class Applet extends Panel
```

Since `Applet` is not abstract, therefore any class which extends it is not required to override/implement all methods in `Applet`.  See the [source code here](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/applet/Applet.java.html) for more information.